# Docker registry configuration

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Output of

```
docker info
```

shows among other lines:

```
Registry: https://registry.fedoraproject.org/v1/
Registries: registry.fedoraproject.org (secure), registry.access.redhat.com (secure), docker.io (secure)
```

- What is the purpose of `Registry` record? I guess that values of `Registries` are used for pulling images.
- How to configure these values? Or in which files are these values stored?

---

My research: On Fedora 26 `docker push` as well as `docker login` works with `https://registry.fedoraproject.org/v1/` by default instead of Docker Hub as it is suggested in man pages: [login](https://www.mankier.com/1/docker-login), [push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/#extended-description). The only file in subtree `/etc` containing `registry.fedoraproject.org` is `/etc/containers/registries.conf` from package `atomic-registries`. This file doesn't seem to configure `Registries` (fully) since it doesn't mention `docker.io`.

EDIT: Docker packages versions: `docker-common-1.13.1-22.gitb5e3294.fc26.x86_64`, `docker-1.13.1-22.gitb5e3294.fc26.x86_64`.

Comment: Please indicate exactly which version of Docker you're using. Fedora and other distressed sometimes use heavily-patched versions, especially in this area of the code.

Comment: I think this is a patched version of Docker where registry is added for searching pulls on different repositories and push to `https://registry.fedoraproject.org/v1/`